# Making several `JPanel`s change their color one by one and not all together with Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I have a `JPanel` that has several (25) `JLabel`s on it, using a timer they change their color every 2 seconds (all panels change to the same color), according to a random order, I only see that order because I've added text prints on each change, but the color changes together, even when I've added a delay between each change (in case my eye wasn't able to see the gradual change) and it didn't help, they all changed color together after a longer wait.

How do I make them change color one-by-one?

The code:

```
public class Billboard extends JFrame{


    private JPanel board;
    private ArrayList<Panel> panels; 


    public Billboard()
    {
        super("Billboard");
        this.board = new JPanel();
        setBounds(100,100,250,160);
        this.panels = new ArrayList<Panel>(0);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container con=this.getContentPane(); // inherit main frame
        con.add(board); // add the panel to frame
        //The timer that is responsible to changing the colors
        ColorGenerator cg = ColorGenerator.getInstance();

        RandomNotifier note = new RandomNotifier(); 
        cg.setNotificator(note);

        JLabel l;
        Panel p;
        for (int i=0; i<25; i++) {
            // create label
            l= new JLabel ("             ");
            l.setOpaque(true);
            // add label to screen
            board.add(l);
            // create panel
            p = new Panel("p" + i,l);
            // link ColorGenerator to panel
            cg.addObserver(p);
            // add panel to panels list
            panels.add(p);
        }
        setVisible(true); // display the frame
        //starts the timer
        cg.start();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {new Billboard();}
}



public class Panel implements Observer{

    private String _name;
    private Color _color;
    private JLabel _label;

    public Panel (String name, JLabel l) {
        this._name = name;
        this._color= new Color(0,0,0);
        this._label = l;
        this._label.setBackground(this._color);
        checkRep();
    }

    //updates the color of the label
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        ColorGenerator cg = (ColorGenerator) o;
        setColor(cg.getColor());
        this._label.setBackground(this.getColor());
        System.out.println(this.getName() + " has changed its color.");
    }

    private void setColor(Color c) {
        this._color = c;
    }

    private Color getColor () {
        return this._color;
    }
}

public class ColorGenerator extends Observable {

    private Notifier _notifier;
    private Color _color;
    private Timer _timer;
    private ArrayList<Panel> _observers;

    //hold the link to the only ColorGenerator
    private static ColorGenerator _cg = null;

    public static ColorGenerator getInstance() {
        if (_cg == null) {
            _cg = new ColorGenerator();
        }
        return _cg;
    }

    protected ColorGenerator () {
        ActionListener changeColorTask = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                Random rand_gen = new Random();
                _color = new Color (rand_gen.nextInt(256),rand_gen.nextInt(256),rand_gen.nextInt(256));
                setChanged();
                notifyObservers();
            }
        };
        this._color = new Color(0,0,0);
        this._timer = new Timer(2000, changeColorTask);
        this._timer.setInitialDelay(0);
        this._observers = new ArrayList<Panel>();
        this._notifier = null;
    }

    public void start() {
        this._timer.start();
    }


    public Color getColor () {
        return this._color;
    }

    @Override
    public void addObserver(Observer o) {
            //...
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteObserver(Observer o) {
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteObservers() {
            //...
    }

    @Override
    public int countObservers() {
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyObservers(){
        if (!hasChanged())
            return;
        if (this._notifier == null) {
            System .out.println ("Notificator has not set for ColorGenerator, can't notify observers");
            return;
        }
        this._notifier.notifyAll(this,this._observers);
        clearChanged();
    }

    public void setNotifier (Notifier n) {
        if (n == null)
            return;
        this._notifier = n;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us the code of the ColorGenerator.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: And what does the RandomNotifier look like?

Comment: It goes over the list of panels in random order and calls the update method of each one. There are other orders, so there are several types of Notifier, according to the order of notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `repaint()` on the JFrame or JPanel when you want the colors to change.